# How can I format the look and feel of my Adaptive Cards like background color, font type and color of the buttons

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, adaptive-design

I'm trying to display an Adaptive Card in MS Teams using the C# .NET Core code for TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearch.

I'd like to know how I can change the background color of my Adaptive Card and if there is a way I can change the color and appearance of Buttons (OpenURL) and the font type in the TextBlock.
I've read about doing it using setHostConfig, but I'm not sure where in my code I can set it.

I tried changing the background color display in the card using `"backgroundImage": "https://www.beautycolorcode.com/abcdef.png"` , this changes the background color, but when I paste my card in the message , I see that there is a top header that contains the App Name and App Icon that get added to the card(from the App Manifest) that are displayed with a white background. I'm specifying the same accent color for my backgroundImage and in the manifest.json. Please let me know what I may be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

this is a question that comes up quite often.

Im afraid the answer is no, you can't change fonts or colors. One big part of Adaptive Cards is that the host (in this case MS Teams) decides the look and feel of cards. You can set colors in a limited way if you choose the danger, accent, warning etc colors but you can't change the colorcode directly. The actual color for lets say danger is picked by the host you're sending the card to.

You can set a background as you've done in your example but that still isn't a real "background color" its just an image used as card background.

The "setHostConfig" part you are talking about can only be used if you are rendering the card yourself. If you want to know which things are customizable if you're the host yourself, have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config

Tim

Comment: Thank you for the inputs Tim!  Can you please elaborate on what you mean when you say >> "The "setHostConfig" part you are talking about can only be used if you are rendering the card yourself."  Also, Is there a way I can set the background image( color)  for the entire card. As of now , it appends the App Name and Icon with Copy links and that ribbon doesn't have a color. Is there a way I can use the same background color there?